# Next and previous buttons not working properly

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react app which renders differnet components on pressing the next and back buttons. The problem i am facing is that the both these buttons are reacting to the previous button press. Like if a first press next then nothing will happen. If then i press back then it is responding to the previous button press of next.

```js
class Card extends Component {
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state = {
      button:"", 
      i:0
    }
  }
  onClick = (event)=>{
    this.setState({button: event.target.id})
    if(this.state.button==="1")
    {
      this.setState({ i: this.state.i + 1 });
    }
    else if(this.state.button==="2")
    {
     this.setState({ i: this.state.i - 1 });
    }
   console.log(this.state.i)
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="App">
      <div >
      <NavBar onButtonClick={this.onClick}/>
      <CardList  i={this.state.i} />
      </div> 
      </div>
 );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.setState` takes a little bit of time to update the entire state, so you cannot reliably execute `this.setState({button: event.target.id})` and then immediately afterward check the `this.state.button` - it's likely that the state hasn't finished being set yet.

Instead, I'd recommend setting your conditional based on the `event.target.id`, like this:

```
if (event.target.id === "1") {
  this.setState({ i: this.state.i + 1 });
} else if (event.target.id === "2") {
  this.setState({ i: this.state.i - 1 });
}
```

I would wait until the top of your `render` method to `console.log` your state for debugging purposes, as it will have completed being updated by then.

For more information on how to use `setState` properly, you can see this [article](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), especially the section entitled "State Updates May Be Asynchronous".

Answer (score 1):

`setState` in React is batched by React, essentially it means, if you do 3 set state calls one after the other, they are all called sequentially.

I recommend reading the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more details.

Now, on to your problem: you are setting a state based on the "previous value" in that state:

```
this.setState({ i: this.state.i - 1 });
```

This will cause "unexpected" behaviour due to the batched mode, as the `this.state.i` could've changed at the time it is actually called.

Here is what React docs recommend to do:

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback))

There is a second signature for `setState` method, which accepts a *function* with the signature: `(state, props) => stateChange` where `props` is optional, if you don't want to use it, no need to pass it.

The common mistake you seem to be doing is reading `this.state` after calling `this.setState`, this will not work.

The code below is not perfect, but hopefully shows, what you need to correct.

```
onClick = (event)=>{
    var buttonId = event.target.id;
    if(buttonId==="1")
    {
      this.setState((state) => {
        return { i: state.i + 1, button: 1 }
      });
    }
    else if(buttonId==="2")
    {
     this.setState((state) => {
        return { i: state.i - 1, button: 2 }
      });
    }
  }
```

**Additional reading**: If you still need to understand how to use functions in setState, I can recommend this article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b